# Couldn't resolve resource @color/colorAccent

Tags: android-layout, android-color

I got this error. Would somebody know how to fix it. All i had written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background_color">#009688</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white_greyish">#EEEEEE</color>
    <color name="button_selectorcolor">#9E9E9E</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your colors resource XML is not showing the color you want to use i.e., **colorAccent** so add this color in your colors.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background_color">#009688</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white_greyish">#EEEEEE</color>
    <color name="button_selectorcolor">#9E9E9E</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">YOUR_DESIRED_COLOR_CODE</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update new version of Android studio and update all plugin. Android studio releasing on 27/01/2020 so update that there are many new features.